# How console log variables inside find method that inside a map method and return an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How console log variables inside find method that inside a map method and return an object ?
That is an arrow function so I should use with function body and return statement.
But I get error if i do.

So how can console log **lbl** and **lbl.label** inside find method?

Yes i should read how use arrow function. (this is exactly what I want to find out, among other things)
Thank you

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLabels((prevLabels) => {
      return [...new Set(savedEvents.map((evt) => evt.label))].map((label) => {
        const currentLabel = prevLabels.find((lbl) => lbl.label === label);

        console.log(`prevlabels: ${JSON.stringify(prevLabels)}`);
        console.log(`currentLabel: ${JSON.stringify(currentLabel)}`);
        console.log(`currentLabel.checked: ${currentLabel.checked}`);
        console.log(`label: ${label}`);
        return {
          label,
          checked: currentLabel ? currentLabel.checked : true,
        };
      });
    });
  }, [savedEvents]);
```

Comment: How about `prevLabels.find((lbl) => { console.log(lbl, lbl.label); return lbl.label === label; })` ?

Comment: Just a side note: this hardcore nesting of functions in functions in functions...is extremly hard to read. Try to do step by step :)